# How to output message during plugin activation

Tags: plugin-development, activation

I am developing a plugin, but during the activation phrase I am constantly facing bugs. However there is no easy way to display error messages, since echoing stuff would result in 'unexpacted output' error. I tried the admin_message hook but it doesn't work. How can I alert the user if some stage of the activation has failed with reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For testing purposes you can use the log system (php_error.log):

```
error_log('Plugin activated', 0);

// Check for DB table existance
if(!$this->hasDBTable()){
    error_log('Database not present', 0);
    if($this->createCELabelsDBTables()){
        error_log('Database was created.', 0);
    } else {
        error_log('Error creating the CE Labels Plugin db tables!', 0);
    }

} else {
    error_log('Database OK', 0);
}
```

To output error to the user without the "Headers already sent" error, you can use the php function trigger_error:

```
trigger_error('PLUGIN OK',E_USER_ERROR);
```

With Wordpress must always be E_USER_ERROR or it won't display the message.

I know the error_log works perfectly since I'm using it, but the trigger_error displays to must information. Try it and see for your self :)

Comment: Do you know where I can find further documentation on the error_log function? I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make it work.

Comment: For those who may come after: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Answer (score 5):

## SOLUTION:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activation_func' ); function my_activation_func() {
    file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/my_loggg.txt', ob_get_contents());
}
```

insert this code in plugin, and after error, view "my_loggg.txt" inside your plugin folder.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to put it at the bottom of the file! Otherwise it did not capture the output.

Answer (score 1):

1) Please remove extra spacing in the inner pages or plugin pages.

2) remove the inline styling in the pages or plugin pages.

its worked for me everytime. i have used many times same method. when the problem error in the plugin page or Wordpress page.

Regards,

Hitesh Nagpal